# Setting cookies to track conversion

Tags: java, php, cookies

I developed web application with java.In that I am displaying advertisements from other eCommerce sites like myntra.com. I want to keep track record that whether user purchase product who redirected from my site.
I am planing to use conversion tracking. I don't want to use third party tools. I want to keep track records on myserver only. How I can set cookie to redirecting page that is security loop hole. My query is

1.How I can set cookies from my server while redirecting to other site?

2.I will add pixel code to advertiser page say

```
<img src="http://example.com/pixel.php?userid=98798&campaign=302&last=8">
```

But how I can identify its actual conversion. User can hit only URL and its conversion get counted .

Comment: well then you need to place your tracking pixel on the 'thanks for your order' page or similar, so it is only ever loaded after a sale

Comment: @ user574632 that I can add pixel.php it creates image 1*1 .With query param I can send sellamount also. But how I can drop cookie while redirecting to other site?